# Getting this page "Your Microfrontend is not here" , on angular single-spa

Tags: javascript, angular, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular

Using single-spa for angular, I am getting this page:

[image]

[image: webpack file from root-config folder]

I need help in fixing the issue, "Your Microfrontend is not here issue".

I have followed all the steps as mentioned in the single-spa docs, and also there is no javascript error in the console, have tried the disabled property change in webpack config file, but still no luck,
here are couple of page contents

[image: app structure]

here `gold-loan` and `vehicle-loan` are the two apps, and the `single-spa-root-config` is the root config

[image: full contents]

[image: ejs having the configuration]

Since could not able to add submodules in github, have zipped and pushed the folder:
https://github.com/ravi-mone/ng-spa

Please help me in knowing what is the issue and also I not understanding where I should add the route links for the apps, like a left side menu holds the routes for gold-loan and vehicle-loan apps, if you can help me with explanation and code changes, basically routing in single-spa.
I will be grateful  if any one help me, I am posting this, after spending much time with no luck,  and asking for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Your Microfrontend is not here issue"?  This is by design in applications bootstrapped with `create-single-spa`.  Have you followed the instructions given in the page?